# QTableWidget Force Single Item Selection

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtablewidget, qtgui

In PyQt how can I force a `QTableWidget` to only accept a single section (so that you can't select more items with <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>crtl</kbd>)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`QAbstractItemBiew.setSelectionMode()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#setSelectionMode) or your `QTableWidget` with the appropriate [`SelectionBehavior`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum), in your case `QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection`.

So something along the lines of:

```
myTable = QtGui.QTableWidget()
myTable.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
```

Comment: Note in pyqt5 QAbstract was moved to QtWidgets